# how to use filer and map together using lambda exp in python?

Tags: python

I was studying python and I came across a topic **filter, map, and reduce**. I know how it works. Now I was trying to use them together as a one line code but I am not getting any solution to it.
I want to first filter the list to get all the even numbers and then I want to use map to double the value of all even numbers.

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

x =  list(filter(lambda x: x%2==0, lst))

y = list(map(lambda i: i*i, x))
```

this will work but I want to use it in one line of code. 
I want to use filter inside map. **ex:

```
 map(filter())**
```

Is it possible to do so? and how ?

Comment: i = range(10),
x = map(lambda i: i*i, filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, l)),
print(list(x))

Answer (score 2):

As a list comprehension

```
>>> [i*i for i in lst if i%2==0]
[4, 16, 36]
```

As a `filter` followed by a `map`

```
>>> list(map(lambda i: i*i, filter(lambda x: x%2==0, lst)))
[4, 16, 36]
```